How to debug Android System Application on Android 11 (AOSP)?
I am trying to debug a system application I have written, but I don't see documentation that works with Android 11 and I have run into errors trying to figure it out myself. I am using an emulator or Ubuntu x86_64.
I ran the app I want to debug and used ps -A to find the PID. Then I tried to execute gdbclient.py -e -p 7984. I get the following error:
\WARNING:root:Couldn't find local unstripped executable in /home/asabbagh/android11-release/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/symbols, symbols may not be available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asabbagh/android11-release/development/scripts/gdbclient.py", line 509, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/asabbagh/android11-release/development/scripts/gdbclient.py", line 501, in main
    do_main()
  File "/home/asabbagh/android11-release/development/scripts/gdbclient.py", line 419, in do_main
    arch = gdbrunner.get_binary_arch(binary_file)
  File "/home/asabbagh/android11-release/development/python-packages/gdbrunner/__init__.py", line 301, in get_binary_arch
    binary = binary_file.read(0x14)
  File "/home/asabbagh/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 24: invalid start byte

Seems like something is going wrong in the communication between the host and target?

If you install Android NDK you will get an appropriate gdb version so you don't have to use that Python based version.

@Robert you can use that for apps compiled with AOSP?

gdb is a general purpose debugger that works with any process. You just need the gdbserver part that runs on Android side. That is the server gdb connects to. Note  that gdb has no Java debugging capability.

Oh yeah. I want to debug the JNI C++ code in an app. Is it possible to attach gbd to this? Or do I need lldb? Which I don't think is included in android 11.

Did you try lldbclient.py? As described gdb is no longer supported, I used visual studio code recently following instructions here: https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/gdb
